# Link to other page than specified

Tags: url, redirect, hyperlink, href

I use a program that has a button which opens a webbrowser on a pre-defined page, let's say https://www.somepage.com. As it is not possible to rewrite this program, I would like to know whether it is possible to change the target into another page, let's say https://www.mypage.com (i.e. without rewriting the program).
Even better would be to open a window in which you can choose between going on to somepage.com  and mypage.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. It depends on your System how that is done.
On a Unix system find your hosts file (/etc/hosts is likely), then add a line like this:

www.somepage.com    www.mypage.com

That should do it. I guess on a Windows it is similar (at least it used to be on 2000 :)